# Does networkx has a function to calculate the length of the path considering weights?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, shortest-path, weighted-graph

I am working with networkx to calculate the **k-shortest simple paths**. `nx.shortest_simple_paths(G, source, target, weight=weight)` returns the list of paths in the increasing order of cost (cumulative path length considering weights).

I am interested in obtaining the cost of these paths. Is there any simple function in networkX to obtain this?

This question is similar to this question: [Is there already implemented algorithm in Networkx to return paths lengths along with paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53796346/is-there-already-implemented-algorithm-in-networkx-to-return-paths-lengths-along).

I believe the posted answer in that post is wrong. From [How to add custom function for calculating edges weights in a graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765852/how-to-add-custom-function-for-calculating-edges-weights-in-a-graph) I made the following solution (see below).

Is this the right approach?

Is there anything simple available in the networkx library?

My aim is to find the cost of **k-shortest path**.

```py
G = nx.Graph()   # or DiGraph, MultiGraph, MultiDiGraph, etc
G.add_edge('a', 'b', weight=2)
G.add_edge('b', 'c', weight=4)
G.add_edge('a', 'c', weight=10)
G.add_edge('c', 'd', weight=6)
G.size()

def path_length(G, nodes, weight):
    w = 0
    for ind,nd in enumerate(nodes[1:]):
        prev = nodes[ind]
        w += G[prev][nd][weight]
    return w

for path in nx.shortest_simple_paths(G, 'a', 'd', weight='weight'):
    print(path, len(path)) # wrong approach
    print(path, path_length(G,path,'weight')) # correct solution
    print("--------------")
```

This will output this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 4
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 12
--------------
['a', 'c', 'd'] 3
['a', 'c', 'd'] 16
--------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, a `k_shortest_path` function has not yet been implemented in NetworkX, even though the [demand](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/793) is not new and you could find some attempt of implementing [Yen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen's_algorithm) on the web.

A (very) rough solution to your question could be:

```
def k_shortest_path(G, source, target, k):
    def path_cost(G, path):
        return sum([G[path[i]][path[i+1]]['weight'] for i in range(len(path)-1)])
    return sorted([(path_cost(G,p), p) for p in nx.shortest_simple_paths(G, source,target,weight='weight') if len(p)==k])[0]
```

For this kind of graph:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edge('a', 'b', weight=2)
G.add_edge('b', 'c', weight=4)
G.add_edge('a', 'c', weight=10)
G.add_edge('c', 'd', weight=6)
G.add_edge('b', 'd', weight=2)
G.add_edge('b', 'e', weight=5)
G.add_edge('e', 'f', weight=8)
G.add_edge('d', 'f', weight=8)
```

[image]

calling:

```
k_shortest_path(G, 'a', 'f', 4)
```

returns:

```
(12, ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f'])
```

Answer (score 5):

I appreciate @sentence's and @nbeuchat's solution. However, if you have a large graph @sentence's solution takes so much time and nbeuchat's solution doesn't provide k-shortest paths. I merge their solutions to come up with much faster k-shortest simple paths with path length.

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edge('a', 'b', weight=2)
G.add_edge('b', 'c', weight=4)
G.add_edge('a', 'c', weight=10)
G.add_edge('c', 'd', weight=6)
G.add_edge('b', 'd', weight=2)
G.add_edge('b', 'e', weight=5)
G.add_edge('e', 'f', weight=8)
G.add_edge('d', 'f', weight=8)

from itertools import islice
from networkx.classes.function import path_weight

def k_shortest_paths(G, source, target, k, weight=None):
    return list(islice(nx.shortest_simple_paths(G, source, target, weight='weight'), k))

for path in k_shortest_paths(G, 'a','f', 3):
    print(path, path_weight(G, path, weight="weight"))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`path_weight(G, path, weight="weight")`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.path_weight.html#networkx.classes.function.path_weight) as follow:

```
from networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic import shortest_path
from networkx.classes.function import path_weight

path = shortest_path(G, source=source, target=target, weight="weight")
path_length = path_weight(G, path, weight="weight")
```